# Gradle dependency configuration : implementation vs api vs runtimeonly vs compileonly

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio-3.0

Unable to understand the latest `gradle` dependency configurations which are introduced in **`Android Studio 3.0`** i.e. implementation, api , compileonly and runtimeonly.

Answer (score 70, accepted):

Please refer the link : [Android Studio 3.0 New Gradle Configuration](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/dependencies#dependency_configurations) available at android developers official site.

Based on description mentioned in above link:

> - **implementation:** When your module configures an implementation dependency, it's letting Gradle know that the module does not want to
>   leak the dependency to other modules at compile time. That is, the
>   dependency is available to other modules only at runtime. Using this
>   dependency configuration instead of api or compile can result in
>   significant build time improvements because it reduces the amount of
>   projects that the build system needs to recompile. For example, if an
>   implementation dependency changes its API, Gradle recompiles only that
>   dependency and the modules that directly depend on it. Most app and
>   test modules should use this configuration.
> - **api:** When a module includes an api dependency, it's letting Gradle know that the module wants to transitively export that
>   dependency to other modules, so that it's available to them at both
>   runtime and compile time. This configuration behaves just like compile
>   (which is now deprecated), and you should typically use this only in
>   library modules. That's because, if an api dependency changes its
>   external API, Gradle recompiles all modules that have access to that
>   dependency at compile time. So, having a large number of api
>   dependencies can significantly increase build times. Unless you want
>   to expose a dependency's API to a separate test module, app modules
>   should instead use implementation dependencies.
> - **compileOnly:** Gradle adds the dependency to the compilation classpath only (it is not added to the build output). This is useful
>   when you're creating an Android library module and you need the
>   dependency during compilation, but it's optional to have present at
>   runtime. That is, if you use this configuration, then your library
>   module must include a runtime condition to check whether the
>   dependency is available, and then gracefully change its behavior so it
>   can still function if it's not provided. This helps reduce the size of
>   the final APK by not adding transient dependencies that aren't
>   critical. This configuration behaves just like provided (which is now
>   deprecated).
> - **runtimeonly:** Gradle adds the dependency to the build output only, for use during runtime. That is, it is not added to the compile
>   classpath. This configuration behaves just like apk (which is now
>   deprecated).

Comment: It's not clear the difference between `implementation` and `runtimeOnly`. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51127422/gradle-difference-between-implementation-and-runtime