# Gradle - difference between implementation and runtime

Tags: gradle

Having read this [Gradle documentation](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_library_plugin.html#sec:java_library_separation) I understand the difference between `api` and `implementation`. However I'd like to know if there's a difference between `implementation` and the deprecated `runtime`.

According to [this table](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_library_plugin.html#sec:java_library_configurations_graph) there is no difference in behavior, but using `runtime` in practice seems to "leak" the compile classpath when I was trying it out and so the classes I was trying to hide was actually being exposed to the consuming module.

Comment: Hmm... The `runtime` configuration extends from `compile` and is described that way in [the doc](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_plugin.html#sec:java_plugin_and_dependency_management), so having compile dependencies available to consuming modules makes sense. Is the same not true in your tests for the `implementation` configuration? Because that configuration is also documented as extending from `compile`.

Comment: No it doesn't. I noticed that doc you linked is missing the `api` task which is probably more aligned to the behavior of `compile` in that transitive dependencies are added to the compile classpath.

Comment: I'm not sure that this is an appropriate Q for StackO but `api` and `implementation` were introduced in Gradle 3.4 with the Java Library plugin: release notes [here](https://docs.gradle.org/3.4/release-notes.html?_ga=2.166993150.1191609754.1530405977-489238126.1480966155#the-java-library-plugin). It states that the motivation is to avoid leaking the compile classpath. Also, note that `runtime` (deprecated) is different from `runtimeOnly`. I'm reasonably sure that `runtime` does leak, hence the improvements.

Comment: @MichaelEaster thanks. Why do you say it's not appropriate for SO?

Answer (score 14):

`implementation` dependencies are added to the compilation classpath of the project they are declared in. That is not the case for `runtime` dependencies.

If you're talking purely about how `implementation` and `runtime` dependencies affect consumers of the project, the [4.6 release notes](https://docs.gradle.org/4.6/release-notes.html#compile/runtime-scope-separation-in-pom-consumption) state that `runtime` dependencies have always been included on the compilation classpath, which is why you're seeing the leakage.

If you published a library with `implementation` dependencies, those dependencies would be marked as `runtime` scope in the POM, and I suspect that they would also be included in the compilation classpath of consuming projects. You would need to enable the `IMPROVED_POM_SUPPORT` feature to change that.

Comment: 1+, you have to always reason from the perspective of the project the dependency is used in, and the caller.