# Gradle: If I changed a dependency from "implementation" to "runtime" and the project still compiles, could there be issues?

Tags: java, gradle, build.gradle

I have a project using multiple dependencies. I suspect one dependency to be needed only at runtime, but I'm not 100% sure.

In gradle, I changed the dependency from `implementation` to `runtimeOnly`. The project compiles just fine.

Could there be negative effects from this change?

Comment: [Implementation vs Runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51127422/gradle-difference-between-implementation-and-runtime)

Comment: @SuryakantBharti the question you linked, while useful, refers to the deprecated `runtime`, not `runtimeOnly`.

Answer (score 0):

If you changed dependency from `implementation` to `runtimeOnly` then it means that the project didn't require this dependency during compilation. All should be fine as the runtime classpath didn't change.

The only issues that I can think of are:

1. The changed dependency being a `javac` annotation processor like Lombok, which should be using `compileOnly` and `annotationProcessor` instead of `implementation`.
2. You have a custom logic for assembling and packaging the artifact which depends on the `implementation` keyword.

Comment: Java can compile a class at runtime. If such a compilation occurs, and the compilation has dependencies, could changing `implementation` to `runtimeOnly` cause issues?

Comment: Which compilation? There is compilation of byte code to machine code by JVM but usually not source code to byte code. Are you shipping a compiler (like ECJ) with your application and you compile the source code? Even so `runtimeOnly` would still make the dependency present during runtime so the compilation should work.

Comment: The JavaCompiler from the javax.tools package, which can compile some stuff on the fly, like this:

compiler.run(null, null, "-cp", paths, "path/to/my/file.java");